# Kill all processes except those with access is denied error

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to create a windows application in C# with the feature that when it runs then all processes except its own gets killed.

I am using the following logic:

1. Get all the processes and get them stored in a list.
2. Create an exception list(list which will have all the process names which are allowed to run).
3. Compare all running processes with exception list. if any process other than mentioned are running then it gets killed.

But there are some process which are not allowed to be killed i.e. `access is denied`
in that case add those processes to exception list.

But the problem is that this code runs and after sometime screen hangs and application gets closed.

Here is the code

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
string[] recProc = { "winlogon", "VCSExpress", "media player.vshost","VCSExpress", "taskmgr", "smss", "csrss", "wininit", "csrss", "services", 
    "lsass", "lsm", "svchost", "winlogon", "WLTRYSVC", "wlanext", "conhost", "BCMWLTRY", 
    "AvastSvc", "spoolsv", "svchost", "AERTSr64", "btwdins", "NitroPDFDriverService", "NLSSRV32",
    "QDLService2kDell", "dwm", "taskhost", "explorer", "RAVCpl64", "AvastUI", "SearchIndexer", 
    "wmpnetwk", "firefox", "bitlord", "IAStorDataMgrSvc", "LMS", "svchost","media player", 
    "UNS", "regsvr32", "Skype", "OSPPSVC", "audiodg", "NitroPDF", "chrome", "AAM Updates Notifier", 
    "mscorsvw", "media player.vshost", "WmiPrvSE", "conhost", "tasklist","regsvr32","RAVCpl64","idle","dwm","conhost"};

List<string> listOfprocess = new List<string>(recProc);

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    int recProclength = listOfprocess.Count;
    int incrementor;

    for (incrementor=0; incrementor < processlist.Length;incrementor++)
    {
        if (theprocess.ProcessName != listOfprocess[incrementor])
        {
            try {
                theprocess.Kill();
            }
            catch(Win32Exception w){
                listOfprocess.Add(theprocess.ProcessName);
                incrementor = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps one of those processes that you killed is more important than you thought...

Comment: You're terminating everything Windows relies on and expecting it to keep running as if nothing happened...

Comment: Normally we don't ask questions for the reason for your program, but it really begs the question: why do you need to do this?

Comment: You want to kill `winlogon`? You know that's a horrible idea. Are you sure this is not a virus you are writing?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the obvious questions about why you are doing this there is an error in your logic.

To see this imagine that there are just 2 processes running on your machine, say explorer.exe and yourapp.exe.

Consider what happens when you enter the foreach for explorer.exe. Inside the inner for loop you check whether the name of the process, i.e. explorer, matches `listOfprocess[0]` (= "winlogon"). So the if condition is true and you end up calling `Kill()` on that process. Which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You evidently meant to allow the process to live if it matches any item in your list.  But instead, you're killing it if there's any item in the list it doesn't match.  That's a problem, because if it does match the first one, it won't match the second, and dies.  If is doesn't match the first, it dies, without a chance to see if any other item is a match.  And of course, you kill your own process.